# Hide/show and make bigger while clicking one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where there are four content and each content has a image. Now, my task is to make the content bigger 
with the image when the user clicks on a particular content. Also, I need to hide all the other content.

Like this is one sample
[image]

Here every image is small and the content is also cut. When the user clicks on the image I need to hide all the other content
as well as I need to make the clicked content appear full and the making the image bigger.
Like this[image]

For this what I am doing is I am loading all the contents with a class and on clicking I am adding hiding the div of both small content and
the small image and making the other bigger content and image as visible.

Also, if clicked again I need to show all the small content with image again.

Now my problem is I have to write the specific div id here so it only makes that particular id bigger. How can I make it more generic?

EDIT:  Added the code

```
$($(this).find(".view-content")).click(function(){  

        if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
                  $($(this).find(".Boardofadviser1")).show(); 
            $($(this).find(".Boardofadviser")).hide();

            $($(this).find(".views-row-3").show());



        }
        else
        {
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $($(this).find(".Boardofadviser1")).hide(); 
           $($(this).find(".Boardofadviser")).show();
            $($(this).find(".views-row-3").hide());
            $(".Boardofadviser1").nextAll().hide();
            $(".views-row-1.Boardofadviser1").hide();
           $(".views-row-1.Boardofadviser").show();

        }
         });
```

This is my HTML Page where all the small content is shown and large content are hidden
[image: HTML CODE]

Comment: Generally speaking you can add classes from the item being clicked (`this` or `event.target`, rather than a specific ID) and add/remove classes on the other items. But you'll need to add some example html to create a complete example

Comment: @Me.Name added the jquery code with HTML page

Comment: Is there any reason why you've set the [click] event handler in the main parent (e.g .view-content) instead of the ``img`` or ``.views-row`` tags?

Comment: I have to specify the particular class for each one this is what I want to avoid If I add more classes I need to add more if/else to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery .toggle() to show/hide content

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.small').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.small').parent().toggle('show');
    $(this).parent().next('div').toggle('show');
  })
  $('.big').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().toggle('show');
    $('.small').parent().toggle('show');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Adviser1</span>
      <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      <img src="img1.png" width="100px" height="100px" class="small">
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">   
      <span>Adviser1</span>
      <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>
      <img src="img1.png" width="200px" height="200px" class="big">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Adviser2</span>
      <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      <img src="img2.png" width="100px" height="100px" class="small">
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">   
      <span>Adviser2</span>
      <p>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</p>
      <img src="img2.png" width="200px" height="200px" class="big">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbbBwg

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the code but as I told here I need to hardcode the class name again can we do without it?

Comment: @shv22 I don't understand the problem.

Comment: first of all in my case there is no div id only classes are there and also I want to make the click function generic enough so that I need not define each time I add a new class like it should detect the class name and change the text accordingly

Comment: And, didn't you say you had four contents? Or will you be needing to add more content at a moment's notice?

Comment: yeah, for now, I have four content but I need to add more content on demand so that's why I need to be a more generic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143181/discussion-between-james-douglas-and-shv22).

Comment: Ok I will check that

Comment: Thanks for the code :) it certainly help me to solve my issue vote up for that

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having additional if/else condition to check if `views-row` holds the `active` class, You have to use `$(this)` context to tell which element you want those classes and show the image under that specific class without affecting other elements that wasn't been called by the `click` event handler yet.

Example:

```
var oViewsRow = $('.view-content .views-row');        
oViewsRow.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Call all DOM elements that have '.views-row' class
    oViewsRow.removeClass('active');
    oViewsRow.find(".Boardofadviser1").show();
    oViewsRow.find(".Boardofadviser").hide();
    oViewsRow.find(".views-row-3").show();

    $(".Boardofadviser1").nextAll().hide();
    $(".views-row-1.Boardofadviser1").hide();
    $(".views-row-1.Boardofadviser").show();

    // Then call that specific '.views-row' DOM element using $(this)
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).find(".Boardofadviser1").hide();
    $(this).find(".Boardofadviser").show();
    $(this).find(".views-row-3").hide();
});
```

Hope this helps for your case

Comment: thanks for the code...here in the code for each click on div it is making it bigger but simultaneously I need to hide the other div views-row-1, views-row-2 etc. how can I do that?

Comment: You can hide other views by using $('.views-row').hide() then show only that specific .views-row that you've click using $(this).show()